# How do I query this data with SQL?

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I am working on attendance management system.

My table data is like this:

```
LogId      EmployeeId      LogTime                          Date
31         22               09:44:00 AM                    2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
40         22               01:51:00 PM                    2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
43         22               02:14:00 PM                    2011-11-04 00:00:00.000 
45         22               07:36:00 PM                    2011-11-04 00:00:00.000
```

I want to display first LogTime (09:44:00 AM) as INTime, Second LogTime (01:51:00 PM) as OutTime, third LogTime (02:14:00 PM) as InTime Etc..  And then I want a summary of all INOut time of particular day.

Comment: Just a side note. I would combine the time and date columns to avoid midnight bugs.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I saw this same question asked yesterday...

Comment: @AdamWenger: hehe - a deja vu, eh? I think we had a guy on SO that asked those "how do I ... with InTime / OutTime" ad nauseum already.... not sure if that's a stadard exam or something that everyone stumbles across.....

Comment: @marc_s I only remembered because my initial reaction was to have this work done in the UI / Display / Reporting layer; after seeing it again, I have the same thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY LogId) % 2 AS InTime,
       * FROM TimeStampTable
```

This gives you `InTime = 1` for time 1, 3, 5... for each `EmployeeId` and `InTime = 0` for the rest.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
select *, Case (ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY LogId)) % 2 
When 1 Then 'In Time' Else 'Out Time' End as 'Row' from @Table
```

Hope this is what you exactly need.

```
select CASE(N.Row) 
When 1 then N.LogTime Else null End as InTime, 
CASE(N.Row) When 0 then N.LogTime Else null End as OutTime, N.* from 
( select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY LogId) % 2 as 'Row',* from @Table ) N
```

Comment: but i need to display Intime and Outtime in seperate column not in one column.

Comment: select
CASE(N.Row) When 1 then N.LogTime Else null End as InTime,
CASE(N.Row) When 0 then N.LogTime Else null End as OutTime, 
 N.* from (
select ROW_NUMBER() over (ORDER BY LogId) % 2  as 'Row',* from @Table
) N

Answer (score -1):

I have tried to do this by dividing the problem into smaller problems
 coalesce function available in SQL Server Can be used for that i have created a table named timing with fields (logid,Employeeid,LogTime,Date)

punch Records can be gathered by using the following query

```
declare @Punch nvarchar(100)
set @punch=''

select @punch=Coalesce(cast(datepart(HH,logtime )as nvarchar)+':'+cast(datepart(MI,logtime )as nvarchar)+(case (row_number() over (order by logid))%2 when 0 then ' Out' else ' In' end)+','+@punch,@punch) from timing order by logid desc

select @punch as punches
```

and for the duration you can use something like this--

```
declare @duration int
set @duration=0
SELECT
   @duration = coalesce((case row_number() over (order by t1.logid) %2 
   when 1 
   then cast(datediff(mi,t1.logtime,isnull(t2.logtime,t1.logtime))as int) else 0 end)+@duration,@duration)
FROM
    timing AS t1
LEFT JOIN
   timing AS t2
      ON t2.logid = (SELECT MIN(logid) FROM timing WHERE logid > t1.logid)
select @duration
```